# Unbalanced cross-sectional data

Tags: sampling, cross-section

My research endeavors to explore the relationship between conflict exposure and attitudes towards international institutions. Specifically, my hypothesis posits that individuals who have experienced higher levels of conflict are more likely to exhibit lower levels of trust in international institutions. The data for my study was gathered through a survey of 1100 citizens from 75 different counties within a single country. I anticipate that individuals living in counties that experienced more frequent bombing during a conflict that took place in the 1970s, but with the survey conducted in 2015, are more likely to hold negative attitudes towards international institutions. However, the cross-sectional nature of my data presents an issue, as it is not balanced. While I have a significant sample size of 150 individuals from one county, other counties have much smaller sample sizes (ranging from 7 to 20 respondents). How can I address this imbalance in my data?